# Why does the my function called by ipywidget button not return an output?

Tags: python, function, button, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I'm using a button to call a function, but the output of the function doesn't seem to be saved.

I'm creating an interactive jupyter notebook which is design to execute functions when a buttons are clicked. For example, the first button called "`Get data`", which would create new variables. Then a second button, "`Analyze data`" would do some analysis on the variables. The problem is that the output of "`Get data`" is not being saved outside the function.

```py
# GET DATA
get_data_button = widgets.Button(description='Get Data')

def get_data(b):

    data = 10
    print(data)

    return data

# DISPLAY BUTTON
get_data_button.on_click(get_data)
display(get_data_button)
```

I'm expecting that after the function I could do

```py
print(data)
```

and return 10

instead it says:

> name 'data' is not defined

Comment: I was able to work around this problem by defining 'data' as a global variable within the function, but I want a more proper solution.

Comment: This seems to be a fairly common misunderstanding, that `return` makes a value available via the name you specified.  That is false, which should be obvious if you consider that `return` takes an arbitrary expression: if you had written `return 10`, what name would you expect that value to be available as?  What `return` actually does is make the value available to the *caller of the function*, as the value of the function call expression itself.  In the case of a button click handler, you're not actually the one calling the function, so a `return` is pointless.

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper. For the example above do you know of a way where I could have the output available after I push the button?

I know this doesn't work but something which would be like:

```python
get_data_button.on_click(data = get_data)
```

Comment: When you ask for a more 'proper' solution, what do you mean? It looks like you want  `data` to be defined in the global namespace of your notebook, so you can print `data` after the button has been clicked in a cell below. The `global` keyword is an effective way to achieve this. You mention a variable being 'saved', but you actually need to assign it to a name to be able to access the object later on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if you were able to get this to work but this will work and will then allow you to use outputs outside a variable.

```
# GET DATA
get_data_button = widgets.Button(description='Get Data')

def get_data(b):
    get_data.data = 10
    print(get_data.data)

    return get_data.data

# DISPLAY BUTTON
get_data_button.on_click(get_data)
display(get_data_button)
```

Pressing the button outputs 10

And you can access the output outside the function using:

```
get_data.data
```

Please let me know if this works now

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot for your answer. I didn't know it was possible to return an output for a function like that. It helps a lot, I appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

`get_data.data` works for me even if I skip the `return` statement.
My layman thought on this, it looks like `.data` sets up attributes of the `get_data` function, treating it as an object? Great work-around, surprising that it requires no explicit `Class` construct.